# How to merge with macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, macros

From input of this kind:

```
CUSTOMERCODE DATE        QTY
890550       16/04/2013  10
890550       16/04/2013  20
890550       17/04/2013  20
890551       18/04/2013  30
890551       18/04/2013  30
890551       18/04/2013  30
```

how may I achieve the following result with a macro?:

```
CUSTOMERCODE DATE        QTY
890550       16/04/2013  30
890550       17/04/2013  20
890551       18/04/2013  90
```

Comment: Please read the FAQ on [how to ask a question](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask)!

Comment: So you want to sum the qty column by customer code and date?

Comment: Hi Billie. Welcome to SU. As Simon says, please read our FAQ and be specific on *"how to ask questions"*..! Simply providing some data doesn't make a question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In essence a PivotTable is all that is all that is required:

[image: SU586940 example]

but if you must apply a macro then you could record something that 'fills in the gaps' so that if, for example, `CUSTOMERCODE` is in `E1` `D2` has the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(E2),E1,E2)` and this is copied down as required.